# Two visible states

Tags: webforms

I'm struggling with two visible states. WIth thE UI this is not possible.

I have an extended text/html field, which shall be visible if the following conditions match:

Scenario 1:

`System` checked AND `System` everything except `Google Kalender` and `Miscellaneous` selected AND branch is NOT `Gesundheit...` ist.

Scenario 2:

`Website` checked AND `System 2` everything except `Google Kalender` and `Miscellaneous` selected AND branch is NOT `Gesundheit...` ist.

That's what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
  - ':input[name="requirements__[System]"]':
      checked: true
    ':input[name="branch"]':
      '!value': 'Gesundheit, Fitness, Ärzte, Kliniken, Labore & Sozialwesen'
    ':input[name="system_"]':
      value: null
      pattern: ^(Gastronovi|OpenTable|Petleo|Resmio|Seatris)$
  - or
  - ':input[name="requirements__[Website]"]':
      checked: true
    ':input[name="branch"]':
      '!value': 'Gesundheit, Fitness, Ärzte, Kliniken, Labore & Sozialwesen'
    ':input[name="system_2"]':
      value: null
      pattern: '^(Aleno|Best Western Hotels Resort|Calendly|Dirs 21|HotelNetSolutions|OpenTable|Quandoo|Tablebooker|Terminland|Vioma)$'
```

Comment: Does it matter if the pattern is in quotes or not?

Comment: If I just use one condition it works, but I am not able to put the two conditons for the visible states together.  I use the following for test:
`
':input[name="requirements__[System]"]':
      checked: true
    ':input[name="branch"]':
      '!value': 'Gesundheit, Fitness, Ärzte, Kliniken, Labore & Sozialwesen'
    ':input[name="system_"]':
      value: null
      pattern: ^(Gastronovi|OpenTable|Petleo|Resmio|Seatris)$
`

Answer (score 0):

I have an old project of mine with complex conditions. There the YAML is written just a little bit different. In your case it would look like this (you see the extra line-break?):

```yaml
-
  ':input[name="requirements__[System]"]':
    checked: true
  ':input[name="branch"]':
    '!value': 'Gesundheit, Fitness, Ärzte, Kliniken, Labore & Sozialwesen'
  ':input[name="system_"]':
    value: null
    pattern: ^(Gastronovi|OpenTable|Petleo|Resmio|Seatris)$
- or
-
  ':input[name="requirements__[Website]"]':
    checked: true
  ':input[name="branch"]':
    '!value': 'Gesundheit, Fitness, Ärzte, Kliniken, Labore & Sozialwesen'
  ':input[name="system_2"]':
    value: null
    pattern: '^(Aleno|Best Western Hotels Resort|Calendly|Dirs 21|HotelNetSolutions|OpenTable|Quandoo|Tablebooker|Terminland|Vioma)$'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it doesn't work.